# cakePHP display Form elements inline

Tags: css, cakephp, helper

I am trying to display form elements inline built using the cakePHP Form helper. It appears it has to do with the classes it creates around the elements. I am sure this can be fixed with CSS but if there is another way i would rather do it right:

```
<?php
            echo $this->Form->create("users");
            echo $this->Form->input("username",array("label" => false, "class" => false, "value" => "Username", "class" => "loginCredentials"));
            echo $this->Form->input("password",array("label" => false, "class" => false, "value" => "Password", "class" => "loginCredentials"));
            echo $this->Form->input("loginBtn",array("label" => false, "class" => false, "value" => "LOGIN", "class" => "loginCredentials", "type" => "submit"));
            echo $this->Form->end();
            ?>
```

Comment: Search your CSS for the string '.loginCredentials', it might have a 'display' value or 'float' applied to it, which is overriding their default display: inline;.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, CakePHP puts `<div>`s around inputs.  You can either add the `'div'=>false` option to each input:

```
echo $this->Form->input("username",array("label" => false, "div"=>false, "class" => false, "value" => "Username", "class" => "loginCredentials"));
```

Or, you can set the inputDefaults for the form itself:

```
echo $this->Form->create('whatever', array(
    'inputDefaults'=>array('div'=>'false', 'label'=>false)));
```

Comment: Hey Dave, thank you for your answer. I used the div => false option, but it will not remove the div around the submit button, is there a way to remove the div around an input[type=submit] ?

Comment: I assume there is an issue w/ your syntax -it should work on a submit button just like any other input.

Comment: To remove the div around the submit button you need to add the div=> false option when you make the Form->end call. So change `echo $this-Form-end();` to `echo $this->Form->end(array('div' => false));`

Comment: None of this is not working for me, I am using CakePHP 3

Answer (score 0):

**My form has only 4 required fields and is generated by the following view:**

```
<div class="users form"> 
<?php echo $form->create('User', array('class'=>'form'));?>
<p class="formtitle">Sign Up</p>
<fieldset>
    <legend class="formtitle">Please complete the form below.</legend>
    <?php
        echo $form->input('username',  array(
            'label' => 'Login',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('password',  array(
            'label' => 'Password',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('password_confirm', array(
            'label' => 'Confirm password',
            'type'=>'password',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('name',  array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('surname',  array(
            'label' => 'Surname',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('email',  array(
            'label' => 'E-mail',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
        echo $form->input('city_id',  array(
            'label' => 'City',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror')));
    ?>
</fieldset>  
<?php echo $form->end('Submit');?>
</div>
```

**Some explanations:**

To add a class to a form tag:

```
$form->create('User', array('class'=>'form'))
generates:


<form class="form" id="UserAddForm" method="post" action="/kultura/users/add">
```

To add a class to an input:

```
echo $form->input('username',  array(
            'label' => 'Login',
            'div'=>'formfield',
            'error' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div',
                'class' => 'formerror'
                )
            ));
```

generates this:

```
<div class="formfield required">
<label for="UserUsername">Login</label>
<input name="data[User][username]" type="text" maxlength="20" value="" id="UserUsername" />
</div>
```

An error in this case will appear in:

```
<div class=”formerror”></div>
```

A sample css style may look like this:

```
.form{
    font-family: Verdana;   
    font-size:1em;
    margin:1em;
    padding:1em;   
}

.form p.formtitle{
    color: #026475;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form fieldset{
    width:40em;
    border:1px solid #FFE545;  
    background-image: url(../img/Contact.png);
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.form fieldset legend{
    color: #026475;
}

.formfield{
    width:30em;
    padding:5px;
}

.formfield label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:12em;
    padding:1px;
    color:#C2A34F;
    text-align:right;
}

.formfield input, .formfield  select{
    padding:0.15em;
    width:14em;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#FEFBAF;

    font-family: Verdana;   
    font-size:1em;

    -moz-border-radius:0.4em;
    -khtml-border-radius:0.4em;
}

.formfield input:hover, input:focus {
    border-color:#c5c5c5;
    background:#f6f6f6;
}

.required input {
    border:1px solid #FBB829;
}

.form .submit input{
    font-family: Verdana;   
    font-size:1em;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.formerror{
    position:relative;
    left:12.1em;
    color:#FBB829;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

dont get me wrong i think you could try this, which should help aswell

```
echo $form->create('Job',
        array(  'type'=>'file',
                'class' => 'form-horizontal',
                'inputDefaults' => array(
                    'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                    //needs to be redefined due to restrictions of the text element we need to define for each input..
                    'label' => array('class' => 'col-sm-4 col-md-3 control-label'),
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'between' => '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">',
                    'after' => '</div>'
                )
        )
    );
```

then you can simply do :

```
echo $form->input('taskfield_id',
        array(  'label'=> array('text' => 'Aufgabenbereich&nbsp;*','class' => 'col-sm-4 col-md-3 control-label'),
                'empty'=>'Bitte wählen'
        )
    );
```

this will output something like this

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="JobTaskfieldId" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 control-label">Aufgabenbereich&nbsp;*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <select name="data[Job][taskfield_id]" class="form-control" id="JobTaskfieldId">
            <option value="">Bitte wählen</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

now you have a form that will give you always this form of input

```
<div> <label> </label> <div> <input /> </div> </div>
```

since i needed to translate some of the labels i need an extea label array for each input which shouldn't be needed if you keep the field names true to your database.

edit:
this is made with bootstrap and cake,
you can also style it yourself since you have full controll of the classes and labels
or without classes

```
label{float:left;width:25%}
label+div input{float:left;width:75%}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP4 I simply added a new CSS file, loaded it after the others, and put the following in it.  This overrides the existing  display:block in original CSS

```
label,
legend {
    display: inline; //change
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    /* font-weight: 700; */
    /* margin-bottom: 2.0rem */
}
```